# Posed in regional mathematics Olympiad 1995

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, integers

Call a positive integer $n$ **good** if there are $n$ integers, positive or negative, and not necessarily distinct, such that their sum and product are both equal to $n$

For example, $8$ is good since 
$$\begin{align} 
      8 = 4\times2\times1\times1&\times1\times1\times(-1)\times(-1) \\
                                &\textrm{and}\\
      8 = 4+2+1+1&+1+1+(-1)+(-1)
\end{align}$$

Show that integers of the form $4k+1$ ($k\ge0$) and $4l$ ($l\ge2$) are good

Comment: hint: Each time you increase a number by 4, you can add the same set of 4 numbers $1\times 1\times(-1)\times(-1) = 1$ for the product and $1+1+(-1)+(-1)$ for the sum without affecting either, since you are multiplying by 1 and adding 0 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers of the form $4k+1$ are good: take the integers
$$4k+1,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{2k\,\text{times}},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{2k\,\text{times}}$$

The next claim is that numbers of the form $4l$ are good. We consider two cases: $l$ even and $l$ odd. If $l$ is even, we have $4l=8k$ and we take

$$2,4k,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{6k-2\,\text{times}},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{2k\,\text{times}}$$

If $l\ge 3$ is odd, we have $4l=4(2k+1)$ and we take

$$-2,4k+2,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{6k+3\,\text{times}},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{2k-1\,\text{times}}$$

Comment: Perhaps I’ve misunderstood the question, but I believe your claim is wrong. Your claim says that if $k=4s+1$ is prime, $4k$ is not good. Let $k=5=4\cdot1+1$. The claim is wrong, because $20$ is the product and sum of the numbers in this list: $-2,10,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$. You incorrectly concluded that when $n=4k$, there must be an even number of $-1$s. There must be an even number of negative numbers, but not all of them have to be $-1$.

Comment: @SteveKrass: Thanks, corrected!

Comment: Your answer looks good now, and it’s much simpler than mine!

Answer (score 2):

As “Your Ad Here” wrote, if $n=4k+1$, take the following numbers:
$$4k+1,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{2k\,\text{times}},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{2k\,\text{times}}.$$

If $n=4k$, where $k>1$, write $n=2^j q$, where $q$ is odd and $j\ge2$, and proceed by induction on $j$.

If $j=2$, $n=4k$ with $k$ odd. Then take these numbers:

$$-2, 2k,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{3k\,\text{times}},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{k-2\,\text{times}}.$$

Their product is positive, because there are $1+3k-2$ (evenly many, when $k$ is odd) negative numbers, and its absolute value is $4k$, so the product is $4k$.

Their sum is $-2+2k+3k-(k-2)=4k$.

If $j>2$, $n=2N$, where $N=2k$ is “good.” Let $a_i$ be the $N$ numbers with sum and product equal to $N$. Now consider these $2N$ numbers:

$$2, a_1,\dots,a_N,\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{\frac{N}{2}-2\,\text{times}},\underbrace{-1,\dots,-1}_{\frac{N}{2}\,\text{times}}.$$

Their product is $2\left(\prod{a_i}\right)(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}=2N=n$, because $N$ is even.

Their sum is $2+\left(\sum a_i\right)+\frac{N}{2}-2-\frac{N}{2}=2+N+N-2=2N=n$.
(Note that $\frac{N}{2}-2=\frac{2k}{2}-2$ is at least zero, because $k>1$ was given.)